# Getting ActiveJob and Sidekiq working with ActionCable for Chat Room

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq, rails-activejob, actioncable

so I have been following the tutorial by DHH on implementing a basic chat room.

The implementation works well enough for me, until I try and integrate the ActiveJob component.

I don't see any error messages in my rails or sidekiq console.  But the _message partial just isn't being rendered.  When I put a binding.pry in the ActiveJob method, all elements seem fine, so I'm guessing it's something to do with the job execution?

To further support this suspicion, when I call the

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast('room_channel', message: data['message'])
```

from room_channel.rb it works just fine!

I've spent hours on this and can't work out how to debug further.  I'm wondering if I need any differnt redis configuration with Sidekiq to make it work.  I've so far just put:

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

in application.rb

Do I need to have a redis initializer also??

Any suggestions on that or any other insights would be much appreciated!

Rails Server:

```
// ♥ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on     http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.2.3-p173), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2016-08-16 16:25:21 +0100    
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT   "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2016-08-16 16:25:21 +0100
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET,     HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2016-08-16 16:25:21 +0100
Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2016-08-16 16:25:22 +0100
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2016-08-16 16:25:22 +0100
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket) 
RoomChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
RoomChannel is streaming from room_channel
RoomChannel#speak({"message"=>"new message"})
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
      SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "messages" ("content", "created_at",     "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["content", "new     message"], ["created_at", 2016-08-16 15:25:25 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-    08-16 15:25:25 UTC]]
(1.3ms)  COMMIT
[ActiveJob] Enqueued MessageBroadcastJob (Job ID: 5981c48d-afbc-4fad-a595-198b56aa90f4) to Sidekiq(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x007f82aa837b90 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://dragonfly/Message/39>>
```

Sidekiq:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q default -q mailers

2016-08-16T15:23:32.583Z 70743 TID-ow892ejts INFO: Running in ruby     2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin15]
2016-08-16T15:23:32.583Z 70743 TID-ow892ejts INFO: See LICENSE and  the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2016-08-16T15:23:32.583Z 70743 TID-ow892ejts INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org
2016-08-16T15:23:32.584Z 70743 TID-ow892ejts INFO: Booting Sidekiq 4.1.2 with redis options {:url=>nil}
2016-08-16T15:23:32.587Z 70743 TID-ow892ejts INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
2016-08-16T15:24:00.652Z 70743 TID-ow89s527k MessageBroadcastJob JID-4ae621ca049eb428ced1c7d2 INFO: start
2016-08-16T15:24:01.153Z 70743 TID-ow89s527k MessageBroadcastJob JID- 4ae621ca049eb428ced1c7d2 INFO: done: 0.501 sec
2016-08-16T15:24:14.351Z 70743 TID-ow89s52rk MessageBroadcastJob JID-fe94b25a9100e83f874ea785 INFO: start
```

app/jobs/message_broadcast_job.rb

```
    class MessageBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob
      queue_as :default

      def perform(message)
        ActionCable.server.broadcast "room_channel", {message: render_message(message)}
  end

  private

  def render_message(message)
    ApplicationController.renderer.render(partial: 'messages/message', locals: { message: message })
  end

end
```

app/assets/javascripts/channels/room.coffee

```
App.room = App.cable.subscriptions.create "RoomChannel",
  connected: ->
    # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

  disconnected: ->
    # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

  received: (data) ->
    alert data['message']

  speak: (message) ->
    @perform 'speak', message: message

$(document).on 'keypress', '[data-behaviour~=room_speaker]', (event) ->
  if event.keyCode is 13
    App.room.speak event.target.value
    event.target.value = ''
    event.preventDefault()
```

Comment: Did you ever make any progress in using actioncable with sidekiq?

Answer (score 0):

It is nothing to do with ActiveJob or Sidekiq. I guess there must be some error when rendering the partial.

Try executing the line in the Rails console,

```
ApplicationController.renderer.render(partial: 'messages/message', locals: { message: message })
```

Hopefully, you get some meaningful errors, such as undefined method or something like.

Comment: Thanks!  Good idea for debugging this kind of thing.   So, I asked a Rails expert about this and they hacked on it for a day and they concluded it was an issue with Sidekiq (or any queueing service) in that they don't cede control back to Action Cable.